# Cycling through labels in visual basics

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I'm really new to visual basics and was given an assignment to Cycle between labels. It calls for two buttons and three labels. 
Lets say the labels are 1 2 3
The two buttons are called "Rotate Left" and "Rotate Right"
When the user presses "Rotate Right" the labels become 3 1 2 and so on while "Rotate Left" does the opposite.

My first button looks like this

```
    Private Sub btnRight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRight.Click
    lbl1.Text = "3"
    lbl2.Text = "1"
    lbl3.Text = "2"
```

Am I in the right direction? I hope I make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does it do what it's supposed to be doing? Seems you're going to need to figure out a way to *abstract* your data and manipulate it with these buttons, rather than simply relabeling controls with a hard-coded string literal - and there are many, *many* ways to achieve this, some better than others; I'd recommend coming up with whatever "works" (don't worry about elegant or efficient code for now, just get it to do its thing correctly), and then present it on [codereview.se] - reviewers will help you improve it, and you'll learn a ton in the process! ;-)

Comment: This is one of those situations where people expect code to just appear to them out of the air without actually knowing what that code is supposed to do. I'm not talking about the end result but rather the steps to get there. If you had to do this same task with pen and paper then I bet you could, which means that you know what has to be done. Write down those steps. You should be able to hand those steps to someone else with no prior experience and they should be able to follow them to get the right result. That's your algorithm and THAT is what you need to implement in code.

Comment: Note that you don't need any programming experience to write an algorithm so it's not a programming question. Once you get to the programming part you should already have an algorithm, so you should be able to show us where in your algorithm you're stuck. If you can't do that then you shouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of TextBox are dynamic, you can store them in a List or Array

```
Dim list As New List(Of Label)
list.Add(lbl1)
list.Add(lbl2)
.....
list.Add(lblN)
```

To cycle it, you just need to go through all the list and switch the number

```
Dim temp As String
temp = list.Item(0).Text // store the first item before it getting replaced
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To list.Count - 2 //If it contains minimum of 3 item minimal
    list.Item(i).Text=list.Item(i+1).Text
Next i
list.Item(list.Count-1) = temp.Text // replace the last item with the first one
```

There are many more efficient way than what I do, but this will explain the basic of List / Array

Comment: Hey Vincent! Thanks for introducing me to Arrays. I have a slight idea of what an Array is now after a few google searches. I think this might be the thing I needed